# Notation to assign multiple values of array at once in vbscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I'm a beginner in vbscript. I defined an array like

```
Dim MyArray(5)
MyArray(0) = "foo"
MyArray(1) = "bar"
MyArray(2) = "foobar"
MyArray(3) = "foo"
MyArray(4) = "barbar"
MyArray(5) = "foofoo"
```

I wondered if there is a syntax like in other languages e.g. PHP like

```
MyArray = Array("foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barbar", "foofoo")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
>> MyArray = Array("foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barbar", "foofoo")
>> WScript.Echo Join(MyArray, "-")
>>
foo-bar-foobar-foo-barbar-foofoo
>>
```

But: `Dim MyArray(5)` declares/defines a fixed/non-resizeable array while the `Array` function returns an array that can grow/shrink via `ReDim Preserve`.

Update wrt comment:

You should `Dim` all your variables (and enforce this rule by using `Option Explicit`). So my code snippet should have been:

```
>> Dim MyArray : MyArray = Array("foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barbar", "foofoo")
>> WScript.Echo Join(MyArray, "-")
>>
foo-bar-foobar-foo-barbar-foofoo
>>
```

VBScript is weakly typed. In general, a variable will get its (sub)type from the assigned value; if you assign the return value of functions returning an array (like Array() or Split()) to a variable it will 'accept' it. Fixed arrays, however, are an exception to this general rule.

Comment: Thst means that I should rather define with `Dim MyArray` ? Will this variable accept an array ?